# how to avoid floating windows cover either other floating windows or text NEOVIM

Tags: neovim

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

As you can see, while I type I get shown the signature of the function and the suggestion. But very often they cover each other.

Moreover, suggestion cover a lot of lines below the line I'm currently in, which could NOT be useful (e.g. I'd like to refer to them)

Is there a way to fix both issues? like pushing floating windows on the rightmost part of the currently window, where probably there are fewer lines of code ?

I think It could be really useful

it's not neovim version's problem.

Comment: Are you using Both nvim-cmp & coc-nvim together? Or any other similar auto completion plugins?

Comment: @Remicaster just lsp_signature and nvim_cmp

Comment: look at lsp signature hompage https://github.com/ray-x/lsp_signature.nvim . On the bottom there's a QnA section "Q: Working with cmp/coq. The floating windows block cmp/coq", look at that answer and see if that helps you

Comment: @Remicaster I don't think it will work. First suggestions do cover signature, not the the opposite; Secondo I was referring to two general floating windows. Btw, ty very much!

Comment: Huh? I don't understand what you mean "it won't work". The reason of the 2 floating windows cover each other is because of you are using the 2 plugins that has the same trigger condition. The QnA provided answers such as placing the window bar on top of the current like which allows both windows to co-exist without being blocked.

Comment: Additionally, about cmp covering the entire text field, you can limit the size of floating window so that it won't exceed certain length in the cmp config.

Comment: For your second question, you can use `set pumheight=10` to restrict the height of popup window. For your first question, open an issue in the respective plugin or find a relevant issue there. I am sure there are already similar issues.